# convert hack into a proper rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an old old app in Rails 2.3.14 I've inherited and I need to turn this SQL into a proper Rails up migration

```
ALTER TABLE gizmo_types ALTER gizmo_category_id SET NOT NULL
```

here is the original migration file

```
class NotNullGizmoCategoryId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    DB.execute("ALTER TABLE gizmo_types ALTER gizmo_category_id SET NOT NULL") <-- offending line
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

This is using some sort of hack "DB.execute()" ...created by one of the former devs
...I need to turn this into a correct "Rails way" migration.

Maybe?...

```
change_column_null :gizmo_types, :gizmo_category_id, false"
```

...not sure.

What would the correct way be?

Comment: Maybe `change_column :gizmo_types, :gizmo_category_id, :integer, null: false` but Rails2 is pretty ancient.

Comment: (1) You should rollback your last edit (which removed the error you added in the first edit). (2) You have NULLs in that column so you have to fix those before making the column NOT NULL.

Comment: Hmm, I found how to remove the nulls but now I have a different problem lol....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66632315/how-to-resolve-contains-null-values-error

Comment: See link in prior comment